# Do European options have to be exercised at a specific time on Expiry day?

Tags: india, options, stock-markets, option-exercise

European Options as compared to American Options can only be exercised on a certain date. As I want to start writing options, I want to know whether it can be exercised by the buyer at anytime during expiry day or only at a specific time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In India, in the money options get exercised automatically at the end of the day and is settled at T+1(Where T is expiry day). This means, the clearing house  takes the closing price of the underlying security while calculating the amount that needs to be credited/debited to its members.

Source: - http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/settlement_mechanism.htm